# Warbler not including ActiveSupport locale files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, jruby, activesupport, warbler

I am using Rails 3.1.3, JRuby 1.7.6, and Warbler 1.3.8

**Note** This was not happening when using JRuby 1.6.7 - but we recently tried to update the JRuby version, and that is when this issue started.

We use Warbler to package our ruby on rails application into a WAR file. That process pre-compiles all the assets and everything works fine (seems to work fine, the command is successful)

We then deploy the WAR file with our Software (which uses a JRuby environment - 1.7.6 - and uses Jetty as a web server)

When the server tries to unpack and deploy the WAR file, we get the following error:

```
org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException: No such file or directory - /home/production/var/tmp/Jetty_0_0_0_0_2525_ui.4.1.4.war____.ed5d4m/webapp/WEB-INF/jar:file:/home/production/var/tmp/Jetty_0_0_0_0_2525_ui.4.1.4.war____.ed5d4m/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/gems.jar!/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/locale/en.yml
from org/jruby/RubyFile.java:838:in `stat'
```

I have checked in the unpacked WAR directory, gone to the gems.jar file, unpacked it, and checked all the files - the activesupport 3.1.3 **en.yml** file is there. The permissions on the file are as I would expect them to be (i.e. nothing seems different than it was previously with JRuby 1.6.7)

**EDIT**
There is a bug between JRuby 1.7.6 and Warbler 1.3.8 - https://github.com/jruby/warbler/issues/197
After encountering that, I tried using Warber 1.4.0.beta2 - which fixes the warbler-jruby bug, but that fix only gets me far enough to receive the missing locale/en.yml file again.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: this seems to be the same error you were having in an [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12803261/i18n-js-gem-not-locating-necessary-files) from last year. Are you still using the i18n-js-gem? And if you pre-compile does the error still go away?

Comment: Hmmm thanks for pointing that out to me, I had forgotten about that! I am no longer using the I18n-js gem, and I am also pre-compiling the assets for production now - and this error does happen still. Though being reminded of that previous question has given me a couple ideas... I will investigate :) Thanks!!

Comment: Hmm though the previous question was about a Sprockets error - this one is getting thrown at RackInitialization... though it is kinda funny it involves the same file... hmmmmmm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your problem, but was unable to. I installed Rails 3.1.3, Warbler 1.4.0.beta2, and JRuby 1.7.6. After creating a new Rails application, I created a controller / view, precompiled my assets, then created a war by running `warble`. I then dumped my WAR into Jetty 9.0.6 (v20130930).

I was able to navigate to the application and plenty of files are located in the WAR at `WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-3.1.3` (253 in all).

Do you have a custom warbler file that might be changing how you build your WAR? Perhaps you can remove it and try "stock" warbler configs.

Comment: Thanks for that validation - I will definitely give that a try today! Perhaps it may also be related to the Jetty version? We are using Jetty 6.1.24

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't easily find a Jetty version that old to try - it appears to be deprecated.

Comment: So, I backed out my warbler.rb config file, used the "stock" settings, built a WAR file with that - and it did work... When I replace the stock settings back with my config file - it causes the error... So now I just gotta narrow down which configuration it is that is the problem... I'll report back when I know more - thanks so much for the point in the right direction!

Comment: So, if I keep my warbler configuration, but remove the gemjar feature (so no longer package the gem repository into a jar file under WEB-INF/lib) - it works. Looks like the gemjar feature was breaking the deloyment... Do you have any idea what the disadvantages are to not using the gemjar feature?

Comment: We don't use it. The [docs](https://github.com/jruby/warbler/tree/v1.4.0.beta2) say "This bundles all gems into a single gem file to reduce the number of files in the .war. This is mostly useful for Google AppEngine where the number of files per application has a limit." So you probably don't need it. It's even possible you will get a speed boost as you no longer have to unpack a jar... :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would try warbler 1.4.0.beta2 just to see if it's fixed

Comment: Yeah, so originally, JRuby 1.7.6 causes a bug with Warbler 1.3.8 - which puts in gibberish characters in the web.xml (and supposedly in other xml files in the WAR) - https://github.com/jruby/warbler/issues/197 - that error is fixed in warbler 1.4.0.beta2 (which I tried out) - but that fix only gets me far enough to receive the missing en.yml file again :)  Sorry I probably should have specified that in the question!