# Jruby 1.7.x compatibility with Warbler gemjar

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jruby, warbler

I have an application using JRuby 1.6.7, Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3.1.3 and Warbler 1.4.0.beta2

For a while now, I have been trying to update the application to use JRuby 1.7.x. Every time I tried (with versions 1.7.3, 1.7.4, and most recently 1.7.6) I would get the following error:

```
org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException: No such file or directory - /home/production/var/tmp/Jetty_0_0_.war/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/gems.jar!/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/locale/en.yml
```

After some help from this question here: [Warble not including active support locale files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19862214/warbler-not-including-activesupport-locale-files), pin pointed that that issue was with the warbler configuration in my application. We had enabled the following configuration:

```
  config.features = %w(gemjar executable compiled)
```

Specifically, the **gemjar** feature was the one causing the issue. With that feature disabled, everything works fine (the WAR deploys perfectly)

I am wondering, if anyone else has run into this, or if anyone knows what the issue might be?

And then more specifically, what are the disadvantages to disabling the gemjar feature of Warbler? From what I can tell, there shouldn't theoretically be anything devastating by disabling it... but I may be overlooking something.

(I do also wonder if the full warbler 1.4.0 release might fix this... but I can't find anything about when a release might be coming out)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are none - actually running a .war with *gemjar* might have issues on some servers (esp. if they do not expand the deployed .war, since then it's quite hard to reference files/resources packaged in a .war while still inside a .jar). on the other hand it should roll fine if things are expanded (even with gemjar) ...

you should definitely report this with Warbler's repository (if not reported already).

it should not be hard to fix - likely a one liner, I know a PR would be most welcome :)

**NOTE:** on the other hand if it worked in a previous JRuby and updating 1.7.x is the issue, than it might be a "regression" on JRuby's side and they might actually fix this if they knew about it ...

Comment: Thanks! I'll definitely try to get this reported with either Warbler or Jruby :)